# Rectangular table with consecutive integers using foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, tikzmath

I'd like to have a rectangular table with integers (like a lottery ticket), let's say 4x9, numbers from 1 to 36.
I assumed that it is easy with tikz, two foreach loops. Like this:

```
\foreach \i in {0,1,2,...,8}{
  \foreach \j in {1,2,3,4}{
    \draw[fill=blue!15] (\i,\j) rectangle (1+\i,1+\j);
    \tikzmath{\k=9*(4-\j)+\i+1;} 
    \draw (\i+0.5,\j+.5) node {\k};
  }
}
```

But the numbers have the form 1.0, 2.0, etc, but I'd like to have 1, 2, etc.
Could you help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,1,2,...,8}{
  \foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \num using int(9*(4-\j)+\i+1)] in {1,2,3,4}
    \node[fill=blue!15, minimum size=1cm, draw] at (\i,\j) {\num};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`\pgfmathprintnumber` solves the problem.

I really don't know why this is so complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It employs two `for` loops.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}   % for \extrarowheight length parameter and 'w' column type
\usepackage{luacode} % for \luaexec macro
\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % make squares 14pt wide and tall
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}

\begin{tabular}{|*{9}{w{c}{6pt}|}}
\hline
\luaexec{
  for i=1,4 do
    for j=1,8 do 
      tex.sprint( i*j .. "&" ) 
    end
    tex.sprint( i*9 .. "\\\\ \\hline" )
  end }
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```